# Load Play Framework javadocs and sources with sbt

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.0, sbt

I've ran the tutorial according to the Play Framework documentation.
Everything works fine so far except that Eclipse is not able to display Javadocs or Sources for referenced libraries.

I created the Play application using the `eclipse with-sources=true` command but without any effect.

I previously used Maven, so I am completely new to sbt. Is there a similar option to "Download Javadocs & Sources" in sbt?

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](http://linwdav.blogspot.be/2012/03/how-to-set-up-play-framework-20.html)

Comment: maybe `with-source=true` ?

Comment: @Aerus, if I read that article correctly, that'll only get you sources and javadocs for the play framework code.  what @mhp is asking for are sources and javadocs for all project dependencies - what if you have a bunch of `com.google.*` annotations and you want to see their javadocs?